# Slow performance of std::complex operator* on some compilers

Tags: c++, performance, operators, std, ieee-754

The performance of my inner loop is suffering due to the NaN tests in std::complex operator*. I know this because if I replace the operator* by my own manual multiplication function that does not include the NaN tests, my code runs twice as fast(!) on real-world workloads. I am happy that there will be no NaNs in the data I am processing, so I do not care about this pedantic IEEE compliance and would like to eliminate it to gain speed.

What I am not sure about is the best way to cause that NaN-checking code to be eliminated. I had thought that -ffinite-math-only should do the trick, but (examining the disassembly) it does not seem to have any effect. Indeed, using all of "-Ofast -ffast-math -funsafe-math-optimizations -ffinite-math-only" out of desperation does not have any effect. Is there some compiler option I could use that would eliminate the undesirable NaN tests?

Frustratingly, I am 99% sure my code *used* to compile to the "fast" version, which leads me to think that such an option does exist. Using the manual multiplication I am exactly replicating fine-grained benchmark measurements I made a few days ago. However, I cannot easily know exactly what has changed about the compile process, because this is a python extension and I noticed the performance drop when I upgraded from anaconda python 3.5 to 3.7. I can only imagine that the compiler options (or something else) being used behind the scenes have changed, but it's not that easy to go back and check (I'd have to downgrade my entire install and hope that I can reproduce the old performance).

I have naively tried subclassing std::complex, and redefining operator* the way I want it. That *does* work, but I am finding that I need to overload a fair few other functions, e.g. conj(), to avoid accidentally reverting to the base std::complex type. This feels like a clunky workaround rather than the "right" way to do this.

Can anyone suggest a good way to achieve what I want (causing the compiler to eliminate the NaN checks in std::complex operator*, in order to get a performance gain)?

Edit: 'codegorilla' requested a reproducible example. The following simple code demonstrates the problem **but** see note below about how my issue seems to be compiler-specific.

```
#include <complex>
int main(void)
{
    std::complex<float> a(rand(), rand()); // input that cannot be optimized away
    std::complex<float> b(rand(), rand());
    std::complex<float> c = a * b;
    printf("%lf\n", c.real()); // output that cannot be optimized away
    return 0;
}
```

Disassemble with

```
gcc -Ofast -S test.cpp -o test.s; open test.s
```

I have been working on OS X, where `gcc -v` reports `Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)`. However, I now see that this appears to be a compiler-specific issue - things compile as I would expect on `gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)` things compile as I would expect (optimized code generated with `-Ofast` but not `-O3`)

With my compiler, a call to `__ZNSt3__1mlIfEENS_7complexIT_EERKS3_S5_` can be seen (and I suspect much of the overall performance issue is that this is not inlined as a compact operation). Inspection of the disassembly for that function confirms that, as per the source for std::complex, the majority of the function is performing checks and corrections for edge cases involving NaNs. This is what I hope to be able to eliminate (which then enables function inlining and subsequent optimizations and, ultimately, a measured doubling of code speed).

Comment: which compiler do you use? plz give a reproducible example

Comment: What kind of NaN checks are you talking about? You can simply take a look at how your standard library implements complex multiplication. For example, `libstdc++` [implements](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/complex#L301) `operator*` using well-known "grammar school" rules without any NaN checks.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I hadn't appreciated that std implementations varied in these details (and so had not checked on different platforms). Now edited to confirm that this is clang/llvm behind the scenes - I had not appreciated that both the std implementation and the compiler options would vary between platforms. That makes my question a bit more of an esoteric one I guess (and I'm still hazy as to why the llvm implementation needs to do the NaN checks at all, especially if the gcc one doesn't bother). Still, if anybody has any clang/llvm specific suggestions, that would be great.

Comment: @Evg the NaN checks can be viewed on line 603 here https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/complex

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with NaNs on both GCC 6.3 and Clang 8.0 (on x86_64 Linux) using `-Ofast` too. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/GX3A-L) you can see the resulting assembly code and there is no NaN checking (no branches nor any comparison).

Comment: Jérôme, thanks for trying to reproduce, that is interesting. Are you able to verify whether the checks are present in your source code to std::complex (i.e. they are being optimised out) or if your std source does not have the checks in the first place?

Comment: It is hard to say from the source directly because built-in functions/types are used. However, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/gQ3T5s) you can see that this is probably the case since Clang does a conditional jump to check for NaNs and both use the `__mulsc3` which should also support NaN values.